# Simplify a geometry on the fly in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 4 to render river ways with labels. The ways can be very curvy, so I'm trying to simplify them on-the-fly in a style function for the labels to go smoothly along the ways.

```
var styles = {
    'lines': new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 1.25
        })
    }),
    'labels': new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: '',
            font: '15px sans-serif',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'red'
            }),
            offsetY: -11,
            placement: 'line',
            maxAngle: 0.25,
            overflow: true
        })
    })
};

function style_rivers(feature, resolution) {
    var stylesArray = [];
    stylesArray.push(styles.lines);
    styles.labels.setGeometry(feature.getGeometry().simplify(0.9));
    styles.labels.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
    stylesArray.push(styles.labels);
    return stylesArray;
}
```

But the "simplify" method won't work for some reason. Can anyone tell why please?

Here is a jsfiddle to play with https://jsfiddle.net/t8Lbjr7r/

Comment: Could you provide  a mock-up of what you want to achieve? i.e. are you trying to simplify the river, alter the placement of the label, both, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the river way in order to alter the placement of the label. The river way itself should stay as it is, but the label should use a simplified version of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by an OpenLayer member: "the units you pass to simplify() are map units. So you'll need to set a much higher value instead of 0.9".
And that worked.